# Remove unchanged (content same) from pending files list in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-power-tools

**This is not a duplicate** of an existing and answered question, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012144/visual-studio-tfs-shows-unchanged-files-in-the-list-of-pending-changes).

It is well known that VS pending files list shows all checked-out files, some of them might have no edits at all. And the recommended solution to remove those files without an edit is to run a TFS Power Tools command, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100981/376692).

However, this doesn't apply to the files that were changed (by a mistake, or on a purpose), but the change was manually reverted. In other words, if the content of two files is binary (or literally) the same, the "Undo Unchanged" command might still think the file has changed and does not remove it from the list.

Is there any way to force TFS PT to perform content-based comparison for pending files vs. latest server version?

Comment: Why do you think that "undo unchanged" is confused when you manually revert a file?  It looks to see if the contents are identical.  It doesn't care what happened between the time you checked it out and the time you run "undo unchanged"...

Comment: @Edward - He means he manually changed the file back to its original state.  The file's time stamp is different but the contents have not changed.  TFS still insists a change has occurred that is worth checking in.

Comment: @Rob I would like to see that data and a repro case - "Undo Unchanged" actually compares the two files and sets the contents from one to another.  TFS ignores a file's timestamp.  (If it the timestamp is actually influencing this behavior then that's a bug.)

Comment: @Edward, as noted in the answer, it only happens with a server workspace.  Local workspaces, work in the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Use local workspaces instead of server workspaces (on VS/TFS 2012 or later). With local workspaces, the only things that show up in the "Pending Changes" window are actual modified files.